# PHP: Why Does array Syntax on a Zero Length String Cast the String as an Array?

Tags: php, types, casting, php-internals

In PHP, you can use array syntax to access string indexes. The following program

```
<?php
$foo = "Hello";
echo $foo[0],"\n";
?>
```

echos out

```
H
```

However, if you access the first character of a zero length string

```
<?php
$bar = "";
$bar[0] = "test";
var_dump($bar);
?>
```

PHP turns your string into an array.  The above code produces

```
array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(4) "test"
}
```

i.e. my zero length string was cast to an array.  Similar "accessing an undefined index of a string" examples don't produce this casting behavior.

```
$bar = " ";
$bar[1] = "test";
var_dump($bar);
```

Produces the string `t`.  i.e. `$bar` remains a string, and is not converted into an array.

I get these sorts of unintuitive edge cases are inevitable when the language needs to infer and/or automatically cast variable for you, but does anyone know what's going on behind the scenes here?

i.e. What is happening at the C/C++ level in PHP to make this happen. Why does my variable get turned into an array.

PHP 5.6, if that matters.

Comment: No you created an array by doing `$bar[0] = "test";`

Comment: @RiggsFolly if you use `$bar = " ";` a space, `$bar[0] = "test";` will show `t`. Why array is not created in this case?

Comment: @RiggsFolly No I didn't, I created a string when I said `$bar = ""`. PHP cast that string as an array when I tried to access an index in the string (`0`) that didn't exist.  Try the script script `$bar = " "` (a single character string)

Comment: What did you expect as result of your assignment? As you assigned value to a 0th element of array and got exactly that.

Comment: @E_p  I would expect an error be raised, or that PHP infer I wanted to extend the string from zero length to one, and assign a character to the first index of the array, similar to how `$bar = " ";$bar[3] = "test";var_dump($bar);` works.  Re: that last one, I would expect my programming language to handle this weird cast consistently.  It doesn't, and I get that happens, but I'm curious as to why.

Comment: A string in PHP is an array

Comment: PHP has all kinds of things you would not expect compared to compiled languages like c, c++. If think in this case php will check for the variable to be empty. if so then the assignment constructs a array. But therefor I need to check the php source code or find documentation about this specific issue

Comment: @RomualdVilletet Or ask on the world's most popular programming Q&A site :)

Comment: I'm not too great at C, but maybe [this](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/91f5940329fede8a26b64e99d4d6d858fe8654cc/Zend/zend_execute.c#L1713) might have to do with it?

Comment: @Don'tPanic seems like the place to look for a answer

'$bar = 0.0;
$bar[0] = "i";
var_dump($bar);'

outputs a warning like WARNING Cannot use a scalar value as an array on line number 4 which is in the same method as you mentioned

Comment: Even funnier: Start with a string variable containing one character, and then assign a multi-letter string to its zero-eth index: `$bar = "a"; $bar[0] = "test"; var_dump($bar);` - result: `string(1) "t"`. And of course, let's not forget, non-multibyte-safeness is around every corner in PHP: `$bar[0] = "Önly";`

Comment: Additionally, this code: `$test = 'hello!'; $test[0] = 'world!'; var_dump($test);` yields `string 'wello!' (length=6)`.

Comment: There is no cast, obviously in the first example you are "accessing" a position of a defined string.  In the second example you are "creating" an array element with index 0.  Should `$s='hello'; $s=array(0=>'test');` trigger an error?  Same thing.

Comment: @AbraCadaver You worded that a lot better than I did in my answer.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I think we're at the point where comments have lost their effectiveness as a form of communication, but see "String Access and Modification by Character" in the manual. http://php.net/language.types.string.  I (think I) understand what you're saying about the array syntax, but that doesn't explain the different behavior for the same scenario with non-zero length strings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the C level the variable is converted to an array when assignment is done by the using [] operator. Of course when it is a string, has a length of 0 and is not a unset type of call( eg. unset($test[0])).

```
case IS_STRING: {
                zval tmp;

                if (type != BP_VAR_UNSET && Z_STRLEN_P(container)==0) {
                    goto convert_to_array;
                }
```

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.0/Zend/zend_execute.c#L1156

Same conversion happens for boolean false values.

```
case IS_BOOL:
            if (type != BP_VAR_UNSET && Z_LVAL_P(container)==0) {
                goto convert_to_array;
            }
```

Confirmed by using a test:

```
<?php
$bar = false;
$bar[0] = "test";
var_dump($bar);
```

Outputs:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "test" }
```

When using true:

```
<?php
$bar = true;
$bar[0] = "test";
var_dump($bar);
```

Outputs:

```
WARNING Cannot use a scalar value as an array on line number 3
bool(true)
```

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.0/Zend/zend_execute.c#L1249

When the value is a type of bool and has a value of true the following code is executed:

```
case IS_BOOL:
            if (type != BP_VAR_UNSET && Z_LVAL_P(container)==0) {
                goto convert_to_array;
            }
            /* break missing intentionally */

        default:
            if (type == BP_VAR_UNSET) {
                zend_error(E_WARNING, "Cannot unset offset in a non-array variable");
                result->var.ptr_ptr = &EG(uninitialized_zval_ptr);
                PZVAL_LOCK(EG(uninitialized_zval_ptr));
            } else { // Gets here when boolean value equals true.
                zend_error(E_WARNING, "Cannot use a scalar value as an array");
                result->var.ptr_ptr = &EG(error_zval_ptr);
                PZVAL_LOCK(EG(error_zval_ptr));
            }
            break;
```

PHP version 5.6 uses ZEND version 2.6.0

Answer (score 4):

I suspect "" is being treated as unset and then being converted to an array.  Generally "" != null != unset, however, php is a little whatty when it comes to that.

```
php > $a="test"; $a[0] = "yourmom"; var_dump( $a );
string(4) "yest"

php > $a=""; $a[0] = "yourmom"; var_dump( $a );
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "yourmom"
}

php > var_dump((bool) "" == null);
bool(true)

php > var_dump((bool) $f == null);
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: f in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0

Notice: Undefined variable: f in php shell code on line 1

Call Stack:
  470.6157     225848   1. {main}() php shell code:0

bool(true)
```

Comment: See the last example I just updated.  Also checking type and using it as a different type will undoubtedly produce different behavior.  If you check the type of $f it will be null even though it's never been set.

Comment: not sure what that last example shows -- plus you're using `==` not `===`, meaning you're adding the `==` type coercion behavior into the mix.

Comment: Your whole question is based on type conversion ;)

Comment: I realize that :)  but this is the only case I know of PHP casting a variable in place for you without asking for an explicit cast.  When you try to `==` an int and a string, PHP will do some converting behind the scenes, but the variables are left in place.

Comment: PHP will convert any var being used, Ex: "1" + 2 === 3;

Comment: Where do you get that `null != unset`? Undefined variables, when used, throw an error but do have a default value of `null`. On top of that, `isset` will actually return false if you have a defined variable with the value `null` meaning that technically the variable "is not set". Also, `var_dump($test === null);` throws an error, but outputs true.

Comment: I was making a general CS statement that unset is != NULL.  When you allocate memory with malloc, that memory usually isn't initialized, hence the calloc implementation.  Also it produces a notice, not an error.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find where this would be happening in the PHP source. I have limited experience with PHP internals, and with C in general, so someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

I think this is happening in [zend_fetch_dimension_address](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/91f5940329fede8a26b64e99d4d6d858fe8654cc/Zend/zend_execute.c#L1713):

```c
   if (EXPECTED(Z_TYPE_P(container) == IS_STRING)) {
        if (type != BP_VAR_UNSET && UNEXPECTED(Z_STRLEN_P(container) == 0)) {
            zval_ptr_dtor_nogc(container);
convert_to_array:
            ZVAL_NEW_ARR(container);
            zend_hash_init(Z_ARRVAL_P(container), 8, NULL, ZVAL_PTR_DTOR, 0);
            goto fetch_from_array;
        }
```

It looks like if the container is a zero length string, it converts it to an array before it does anything with it.

Comment: Whoops same answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is changed to an array when you use array syntax on an empty string is because index 0 is undefined, and doesn't have a type at that point. Here is a kind of case study.

```
<?php
$foo = "Hello"; // $foo[0] is a string "H"
echo $foo[0],"\n"; // H
$foo[0] = "same?"; // $foo[0] is still a string, "s" note that only the s is kept.
echo $foo,"\n"; // sello
echo $foo[0],"\n"; // s
$foo[1] = "b"; // $foo[1] is a string "b"
echo $foo,"\n"; // sbllo
$bar = ""; // nothing defined at position 0
$bar[0] = "t"; // array syntax creates an array with a string as the first index
var_dump($bar); // array(1) { [0] => string(1) "t" }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however *and doesn't have a type at that point* isn't correct. If you're referring to the string, it does have a type: `$bar = "";echo gettype($bar),"\n";`  If you're referring to the array, you're right that the index is undefined, however `$bar = "a";$bar[2] = "b";var_dump($bar);` does **not** cast $bar as an array, and `2` is undefined.

Comment: I am referring to the item at index 0 if the string, like I said: "because index 0 is undefined, and doesn't have a type at that point". In your example you just gave, `$bar = "a"` sets bar as a string, which is internally stored as an array of bytes ([ref](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr)). Because of this, I would *assume* that until a variable has an actual string value (ie bytes assigned to indices), using array syntax will allow you to store items not limited to bytes, becoming a normal array.